# Create Kotlin data class for xml

Tags: xml, kotlin, data-class

Can anyone help with creating a Kotlin data class to use with Retrofit  and the simplexml converter for this seemingly simple xml?

```
<texts>
<text id="3">
<title>Veðurhorfur á höfuðborgarsvæðinu</title>
<creation>2022-11-03 10:20:30</creation>
<valid_from>2022-11-03 12:00:00</valid_from>
<valid_to>2022-11-05 00:00:00</valid_to>
<content>Norðlæg </content>
</text>
<text id="6">
<title>Veðurhorfur</title>
<creation>2022-11-03 08:41:53</creation>
<valid_from>2022-11-05 12:00:00</valid_from>
<valid_to>2022-11-10 12:00:00</valid_to>
<content>Austan- </content>
</text>
</texts>
```

Comment: What have you tried that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://mak95.medium.com/parsing-xml-data-via-retrofit-2-x-using-kotlin-3ce007d00cf8), the following should work:

```kotlin
@Root(name = "texts", strict = false)
class Texts @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field:ElementList(inline = true)
    var textList: List<Text>? = null
)

@Root(name = "text", strict = false)
class Text @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field:Attribute(name = "id")
    var id: String = "",
    @field:Element(name = "title")
    var title: String = "",
    @field:Element(name = "creation")
    var creation: String = "",
    @field:Element(name = "valid_from")
    var validFrom: String = "",
    @field:Element(name = "valid_to")
    var validTo: String = "",
    @field:Element(name = "content")
    var content: String = "",
)
```

Comment: Replacing LocalDateTime with just String and this works. I had tried this https://etemnogrudova.medium.com/parsing-xml-using-retrofit2-in-kotlin-8e0ff6420bd7 with no luck. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: It seems that the problem using https://etemnogrudova.medium.com/parsing-xml-using-retrofit2-in-kotlin-8e0ff6420bd7
approach involves Path. If I add @field:Path("texts") to the solution provided by usar3738870 the response is null. Why would that be?

Comment: I've edited my answer with `String` instead of `LocalDateTime`. Why would you need to use `Path`? Can you add an example to your original question?

Comment: Why Path? Take a look at the reference in my comment for an answer to your question.

Comment: It's only needed if you want to "skip" an XML object (not represent it in Kotlin with a class). In the article, it's used because the "channel" object is skipped. Since your structure is simpler, you do not need `@Path`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wonder if you could also help with another problem and that is <br/> tags inside the content that break the flow.

Comment: Sure, but you should open a new question on Stackoverflow so you can properly describe the problem